# What should be added to the Dockerfile to enable importing any module from any location within the project?

Tags: python, docker

Project structure:

```
project_dir
├── backend
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module.py
    __init__.py
└── frontend
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── main_script.py
    __init__.py
```

In main_script.py:

```
from backend import module.py
```

During local execution, I was able to perform this import by adding the full path to the project in main_script.py:

```
import sys
import os
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
project_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(current_dir))
project_path = os.path.join(project_root, 'project_dir')
sys.path.append(project_path)
```

But when running the container, the backend module is not visible from main_script.py:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'

How can this be fixed?

I have tried adding

```
'ENV PYTHONPATH=/app'
```

to the Dockerfile, but it did not help

Comment: As a first step, delete the path you show that manipulates `sys.path`; this shouldn't be necessary and can make debugging this sort of problem harder.  So long as the Dockerfile `WORKDIR` is set to the project root and your `import` statement is correct (`from backend import module` without the `.py` extension) this should work without any complicated changes.  What does your current Dockerfile include?